# Install gfortran using cmake

Tags: cmake

I would like install gfortran (or gcc or python for example) using cmake.

I know that I can write in my terminal:
sudo apt-get install gfortran

But I have to install a lot of programs in several computers and I would like write something like a "script" but in cmake in order to install all the programs "automatically".

I have looked for in tutorials and forums but I have not found anything.

Thanks

Comment: Just create shell script and list all commands, needed to install dependencies, into it.

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't think that it was so easy.